# Karma: property does not have access type get

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an error in my Karma tests in my Angular application. The error is when I run my tests:

`Failed: Property activePropertyChanged does not have access type get`

I'm trying to mock a service called `ModuleSpecService`. In this service there's the following getter:

```js
get activePropertyChanged(): Observable<SpecificationPropertyObject> {
    return this.activePropChangedSubject.asObservable();
}
```

And in my `spec` file I mock it like this:

```js
spyOnProperty(moduleSpecServiceMock, 'activePropertyChanged', 'get').and.returnValue(of());

// then, in configureTestingModule() I define/mock the service like this:
providers: [{ provide: ModuleSpecService, useValue: moduleSpecServiceMock }]
```

So there's clearly a getter in my service which I want to mock. If I remove the line with `spyOnProperty()` it throws the following error:

`TypeError: this.moduleSpecService.activePropertyChanged.subscribe is not a function`

so I definitely need the mock.

Any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: I remember this being an old bug in jasmine. Can you try to remove the 'get' parameter, because it should default to the getter anyways. If that doesn't work, update your testing dependencies

Comment: That still doesn't work unfortunately. This really seems to be a bug. I managed to fix it with a workaround though (will post an answer)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since this seems to be a bug in jasmine I managed to fix this with a workaround:

Instead of this:

```
spyOnProperty(moduleSpecServiceMock, 'activePropertyChanged', 'get').and.returnValue(of());
```

I defined the property like this:

```
(moduleSpecServiceMock as any).activePropertyChanged = of();
```

I had to cast it as `any`, because if not, it (correctly) told me that `activePropertyChange` is a `read-only` property (since it has only a getter).

Not the best solution, but at least it works :)

Comment: I had the same problem. Mine was a GlobalService that someone had written which included a user = some.asObservable() property.   @dave0688 - your suggestion fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

I found a slightly different solution to this problem:

```
Object.defineProperty(moduleSpecServiceMock, 'activePropertyChanged', { value: of() });
enter code here
```

this solution even rewrites private values

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spread syntax:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
const moduleSpecServiceMock = {
  ...jasmine.createSpyObj('moduleSpecServiceMock ', ['']),
  activePropertyChanged: of()
} as jasmine.SpyObj;
```

This allows you to set private properties and getters without the need for `as any` syntax.

One great benefit of this is that if you refactor the getter name then the test property will also update, with the `as any` syntax you lose the typings and ability to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that error, creating a `get` property in the **service**, so:

`.spec.ts` file:

```
spyOnProperty(moduleSpecServiceMock, 'activePropertyChanged', 'get').and.returnValue(of("Test"));
```

`.service.ts` file:

```
get activePropertyChanged(): Observable<any> {
 return of({...element});
}
```

Comment: Already there is a getter and still he gets the error!!